# how to make save / load game functions in pygame?

Tags: python, load, save, pygame

I need to make save / load game functions for my rpg. I can save the location of my player, but what I want is to freeze the entire screen at one point like it is done in emulators like vba and snes9x. Or maybe to make save locations where I can save the game and start again from. Can anyone tell me how you do these things? any code is welcomed even theorybased pseudocode.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) to serialize Python data. This has nothing to do with pygame.

So if your game state is completely stored in the object `foo`, to save to file "savegame" (`import pickle` first):

```
with open("savegame", "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(foo, f)
```

To load:

```
with open("savegame", "rb") as f:
    foo = pickle.load(f)
```

The game state is all the necessary information you need to restore the game, that is, the game world state as well as any UI state, etc. If your game state is spread across multiple objects with no single object that composes them, you can simply pickle a list with all the needed objects.

Comment: Thanks! Making save/load functions as  it is! ^_^

Comment: It's better to use SQL database because saving object in pickle form takes so much space. Instead, we can store important variables and states in the database. On starting, query the database and assign the states and values to respective variables.