# Can Python or Pygame create separate files in order to save game progress?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game in which I want it possible to save. Is there some way to program python or pygame so that it creates a notepad (or something similar) file documenting a players progress? I am fairly new to python, so please explain it easily.
Thanks.

Comment: I don't know about pygame, but http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: Also! Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420311/how-to-make-save-load-game-functions-in-pygame :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Pickle](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html) to serialize variables to a file.